# Amount of rain fall today

Tags: java, machine-learning, regression, feature-extraction

I want to calculate the **amount of rainfall** today in mm.So I want to know first whether is **Linear Regression** or **Logistic Regression** problem and how to calculate if i have datasets with some attributes with large no. of instances.
And how to know when to use **feature scaling** & how my program effects if i don't use **feature scaling** where it is neccessary.
Can I have java code of feature scaling.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about machine learning not software development. Try http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Daniel Please, if you indicate such fact, [give a references to the appropriate stack exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stackexchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms).

Comment: @alfa I already given answer to you!!!Then you asked similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calculating the amount of rainfall today then you should go for **Linear Regression** which will best suits this problem.
Since amount belongs to R(real) then it is a concrete value, if you have classification especially a binary classification then you must go with **Logistic Regression**.
suppose there are 6 attributes in calculating the amount of rainfall today then your model must be:-
 `y = w(0)+x(1)w(1)+x(2)w(2)+x(3)w(3)+x(4)w(4)+x(5)w(5)+x(6)w(6)` 
 `y`  is amount of rainfall you want to predict.
Where `x(1)...x(6)` are attributes and `w(0)...w(6)` what you have to calculate.
Then you should a **loss function** which you have reduce:-
[image]

Now you want to calculate w(0)...w(6).
Now use **gradient descent** in it.
[image]
//Actually i donot have any image of gradient descent but i can make you understand from this.
`theta(j)` is `w(j)` and `alpha` is learning rate. And `E` is `J(theta)` ,`t(p)` is given value where `y(p)` is predictive value which is original `y`.

And [feature scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling) is done when data is too sparse this can be done dividing all elements by maximum element.This is done to normalize the independent data.So first feature selection then scaling.

More about [Linear regression](http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs449/linear1.html).
**Why logistic regression cannot be applied here?**
Because in **logistic regression** we get s-shaped curved which best suits for binary classification .
Above 0.5 take 1 or true or below 0.5 take 0 or false.
[image]
Hope this is useful to you.

Comment: Try to read it you will get your answer!!!